# How do I add a value to a tag field type using the entries service saveEntry method?

Tags: plugin-development, entries, tags, fieldtypes, elementtype

I am updating an entry using the entries service, I want to add a tag value into a tag field type (classifiedTags).

```
$entry = craft()->entries->getEntryById(120);
$entry->getContent()->classifiedTags = 'tagtest';
$entry->title = 'Updating title to this';
$entry->getContent()->description = 'this is the new description';
craft()->entries->saveEntry($entry);
```

It runs and updates everything except the tag field (classifiedTags).

If I change it from a string to array like below:

```
$entry->getContent()->classifiedTags = array('tagtest');
```

It gives me this error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`ggmg_craft`.`craft_relations`,
>   CONSTRAINT `craft_relations_targetId_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`targetId`)
>   REFERENCES `craft_elements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE). The SQL
>   statement executed was: INSERT INTO `craft_relations` (`fieldId`,
>   `sourceId`, `sourceLocale`, `targetId`, `sortOrder`, `dateCreated`,
>   `dateUpdated`, `uid`) VALUES (:row0_col0, :row0_col1, NULL,
>   :row0_col3, :row0_col4, :row0_col5, :row0_col6, :row0_col7). Bound
>   with :row0_col0='43', :row0_col1='31823', :row0_col3='tagtest',
>   :row0_col4=1, :row0_col5='2016-07-14 21:16:04', :row0_col6='2016-07-14
>   21:16:04', :row0_col7='d2228ed9-cc60-478d-929c-98efd776b63c'

Which leads me to believe I am getting warmer.

Craft CMS v 2.6.2796
PHP v 5.6.13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Tags field `classifiedTags` needs an array of tag IDs, not slugs/titles. Also, if this is an existing entry and you want to retain tags already added to the field, you'll need to pull the existing tag IDs using `$entry->classifiedTags->ids()` and merge with those.

```
$tag = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Tag, [
    'groupId' => 1,
    'slug' => 'tagtest',
])->first();
if ($tag) {
  $existingTags = $entry->classifiedTags->ids();
  $entry->getContent()->setAttribute('classifiedTags', array_merge($existingTags, [$tag->id]));
}
```

Note that if the tag doesn't already exist, you'll need to create it using the [TagsService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TagsService):

```
$tag->groupId = 1;
$tag->getContent()->title = 'tagtest';
$success = craft()->tags->saveTag($tag);
```